# Detect if CKEditor used a keyup event, or prevent its propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, ckeditor

### In short

Is there a way in which, when listening to a native event, I can detect if the event was somehow used by CKEditor before it propagated to my listener, or prevent it from propagating at all?

### Use case

I'm listening to the `keyup` event using jQuery, to detect when <kbd>escape</kbd> is pressed. When it is, the user is prompted if they want to discard changes, and the CKEditor instance is destroyed and its element removed from the DOM.

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(e){
  if(e.which==27){
    CKEDITOR.instances.myDiv.destroy();
    $('#myDiv').remove();
  }
});
```

The problem here is that CKEditor allows the user to interact with certain UI elements using the <kbd>escape</kbd> key. For instance to close a dialog window or drop-down list.

So my event should only execute its code *if* CKEditor did not already use the event to close a UI element of its own.

### Attempt

I tried to listen to the `dialogShow` and `dialogHide` events to detect if a dialog window is open, and my action should thus be ignored. This didn't work for two reasons:

- CKEditor handles the event first, so by the time the event propagates to my listener, no dialog windows are open and my code is executed.
- Even if it *would* work, it wouldn't for drop-down lists as they do not trigger the `dialog*` events.

### Ideas

I don't know enough about the workings of CKEditor to come up with a solution, but I think I'm looking for something along the lines of:

- A setting in CKEditor to prevent event propagation: `CKEDITOR.instances[0].noEventPropagation = true`
- An indication in the original event object: `if(event.CKEditorWasHere){/*do nothing*/}`
- A plugin providing functionality that I can use.
- Worst case scenario: A setTimeout in the `dialogHide` event which I'll use to suppress my own events for a short time.

### So

Maybe I'm completely overlooking something. This seems to me like a common problem which should have a simple solution.

Thanks for your time.